# BeautifulSoup not finding all items in Amazon

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wrote the following source code to scrape titles/authors from Amazon books. However, "find all" only returns me information from the first 30 books instead of all 50 books on the page.

I noticed that the first 30 books are the ones that have already been loaded without scrolling the search bar, but I'm not sure if this is the reason.

```
s = HTMLSession()
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-Arts-Photography/zgbs/digital-text/154607011/ref=zg_bs_nav_digital-text_3_157325011"
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
books = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"_p13n-zg-list-grid-desktop_truncationStyles_p13n-sc-css-line-clamp-1__1Fn1y"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `requests` library and change the selector to something that is less dynamic than the `class` value you have used in your code. See below sample code using requests

```py
from requests import session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = session()
url = "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store-Arts-Photography/zgbs/digital-text/154607011/ref=zg_bs_nav_digital-text_3_157325011"
r = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
books = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"gridItemRoot"})

print(len(books))
```

You will get below print out in the terminal

```sh
50
```